# split a specific pandas dataframe into two lists

Tags: python, list, pandas, split

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [True, True, False, True, True, False,False], 'b': range(7)} , index = range(7))
```

...(index isn't important) and I want to obtain a tuple:

```
([[0, 1], [3, 4]], [[2],[5, 6]])
```

...or more generally, I want to split df into tuple where first element is the list of list of values from column b, where a==True, and second element is... where a==False. The order in lists should match the order in data frame.
What is the most pythonic (or 'pandastic') way to obtain this?
I'm not satisfied with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [True, True, False, True, True, False,False], 'b': range(7)} , index = range(7))

def splitOnDiscontinuities(elements):
    lists = [[]]
    lastE = None
    for e in elements:
        if lastE is None or e == lastE + 1:
            lists[-1].append(e)
        else:
            lists.append([e])
        lastE = e
    return lists

def weirdThing(df, col1, col2):
    trueElements = splitOnDiscontinuities(list(df[col1][df[col2] == True]))
    falseElements = splitOnDiscontinuities(list(df[col1][df[col2] == False]))
    return (trueElements, falseElements)

print weirdThing(df, 'b', 'a')
```

OUTPUT:

```
([[0, 1], [3, 4]], [[2], [5, 6]])
```